# Form Filling Automation with webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

```
HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
{
    if (curElement.GetAttribute("readonly") == "readonly")
    {
        curElement.InnerText = txtCountryCode.Text;
    }

    if (curElement.Name.ToString() == "phone")
    {
        curElement.SetAttribute("value", txtPhone.Text.ToString());
        curElement.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
}
```

The problem is windows state in not active. i mean i am running other software like browser.

Problem: `InvokeMember("Click")` and `SetAttribute` does not work.

Any suggestion or alternative is appriciated.

Comment: you mean automating while your app is not in the foreground?

Comment: yes. Invokemember is not working when application is not in foreground

Comment: the result of IHTMLElement::click may depend on focus/activation but setting value should not. did you try get value after setting?

Comment: setting and getting value of htmlElement is working fine. but invokemember is not working.

Comment: what does the click do? launch a hyper link? run some javascript? submit a form?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 it submits the form.

Comment: what if you call submit on the form element directly?

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 it works like a charm